# make a library with Opencv (static or dynamic) libraries and then use it with Openframeworks

Tags: c++, opencv, openframeworks

I am working with a ubuntu pc and using codeblocks. I created a library (static and dynamic) with the opencv dynamic libraries, and i want to know if i can use my new library with openframeworks.

I want to do this because openframeworks doesn't have some function that i need, and it makes redefinition of types (that gives me errors).
thanks in advance.

Comment: Could you clarify what you are trying to do?  Are the opencv binaries included with openFrameworks not working for you?

Comment: i have a 0062 OF project and i want to use some functions that i wrote with the Opencv 2.4.2. Is possible to create a library with opencv and then use it with OF? If yes, i should create a shared library or static library?

Answer (score 0):

I've done this in Eclipse but I think is very alike.
When you create the new project you have to set artifact parameters in project proprerties.

You have to specify that you want a shared library, then the artifact name and the extension.